# Jenkins: Run python script using groovy in jenkins extended choice parameter

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to python and groovy.Jenkins version i'm using is Jenkins 2.263.1.
My problem statement:
I have a python code passed with 1 argument which returns the list of values. This is running fine in bash. I want to use the values that is printed from python script as a build parameters in jenkins. For this i used extended choice parameter plugin. Here is the code i tried which returns nothing..

```
return "python3 /usr/local/bin/robot_get_tags /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/eng/Robot-test-suites_development/DT_Solution_Test/02_System_Test/libisis".execute().text
```

```
def task = "python3 /usr/local/bin/robot_get_tags.py /srv/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/eng/Robot-test-suites_development/test_repo_clone/02_System_Test/libisis/testcases/01_functional_test/ ".execute()
task.waitFor()
println task.text
```

The values which are displayed when i run the script in bash..

```
 python3 /usr/local/bin/robot_get_tags.py /srv/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/eng/Robot-test-suites_development/test_repo_clone/02_System_Test/libisis/testcases/01_functional_test/

E, ET, ISIS_ADJ, ISIS_ADJ], ISIS_ADJ_L1
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!!